# Formatted directory tree in bash

Tags: bash

I want to print the directory tree representing only the directories in bash in the following formatted way using a simple for loop and some pattern matching operators:

```
.
|
|-------root
|       |
|       |-------d1
|       |       |
|       |       |-------d11
|       |       |-------d12
|       |       |-------d13
|       |       |-------d14


|        |-------d2
...
```

I am trying to do this using the following script

```
 # this function calls itself recursively till it encounters a file which is
 # not a directory
 recdir()
 {
    #echo "$@"
    formatting=${formatting%$dashes}

    for file in "$@"; do

            # move one directory down
            thisfile=$thisfile/$file

            if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
                    formatting=$formatting$singletab$vert$dashes
            else
                    formatting=${formatting%$singletab*}
                    formatting=$formatting$singletab$vert$dashes
            fi

            if [ -d "$thisfile" ]; then
                    echo -e "$formatting$file"
            fi

            if [ -d "$thisfile" ]; then
                    count=0
                    recdir $(command ls $thisfile)
            fi
            count=$(( $count + 1 ))

            if [ $count -le 1 ]; then
                    formatting=${formatting%$singletab*}
            fi
            # removes the string and moves one directory up
            thisfile=${thisfile%/*}
    done
}

recls()
{
     singletab="       "
     vert="|"
     dashes="-------"

     # This variable will be used in recdir() to detect whether it has reached
     # a directory which has no directory in it and hence remove the trailing
     # spaces which were added to it in recdir() function.

     count=0
     echo "."
     echo -e "$vert"
     for tryfile in "$@"; do

             if [ -d "$tryfile" ]; then
                     formatting="$vert$dashes"
                     echo -e $formatting$tryfile
                     thisfile=$tryfile
                     # makes call to recur
                     recdir $(command ls $tryfile)
             fi
     done

     unset singletab formatting vert dashes tryfile
}
```

I have added these two functions in my .bash_profile file, and trying to call them as:

```
recls nameofdirectory/
```

And the output which I am getting is inconsistent. I do see one problem in this script that is the removal of spaces in recdir() function but still it behaves contrary to what I am thinking now. Can someone please suggest what changes I can make to this script so as to obtain the desired result.

An example of inconsistent output is:

```
|
|-------V1.2/
|       |-------100
|       |-------DAT
|       |       |-------000000
|       |-------000001
|       |-------000002
|       |-------000003
|       |-------000004
|       |-------000005
|       |-------000006
|       |-------000007
|       |-------DATA1
|       |       |-------data-msd1-100
|       |       |-------DAT
|       |       |       |-------000000
|       |       |       |-------000001
|       |       |       |-------000002
|       |       |       |-------000003
|       |       |       |-------000004
|       |       |       |-------000005
|       |       |       |-------000006
|       |       |       |-------000007
|       |       |       |-------data-msd2-100
|       |       |       |-------DAT
|       |       |       |       |-------000000
|       |       |       |       |-------000001
|       |       |       |       |-------000002
|       |       |       |       |-------000003
...
```

And the output should have been like this:

```
.
|
|-------V1.2/
|       |-------100
|       |       |-------DAT
|       |       |        |-------000000
|       |       |        |-------000001
|       |       |        |-------000002
|       |       |        |-------000003
|       |       |        |-------000004
|       |       |        |-------000005
|       |       |        |-------000006
|       |       |        |-------000007
|       |       |-------DATA1
|       |       |        |-------data-msd1-100
|       |       |        |       |-------DAT
|       |       |        |       |       |-------000000
|       |       |        |       |       |-------000001
|       |       |        |       |       |-------000002
|       |       |        |       |       |-------000003
|       |       |        |       |       |-------000004
|       |       |        |       |       |-------000005
|       |       |        |       |       |-------000006
|       |       |        |       |       |-------000007
|       |       |        |-------data-msd2-100
|       |       |        |       |-------DAT
|       |       |        |       |       |-------000000
|       |       |        |       |       |-------000001
|       |       |        |       |       |-------000002
|       |       |        |       |       |-------000003
...
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You can use the command `tree` which does exactly what you want, e.g. [`tree -d`](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-show-directory-structure-command-line/)

Comment: Will you please add an example of inconsistent output from your script?

Comment: @Leon Please see the edit which I have made, it contains an inconsistent output with an example of what the correct output should have been

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type d | sed -e "s/[^-][^\/]*\//  |/g" -e "s/|\([^ ]\)/|-\1/"
.
  |-storage1
  |-storage2
  |-storage3
  |-cache
  |-temp
  |  |-test
  |  |  |-one
  |  |  |-two
  |  |  |-three
  |  |  |-four
  |-storage4
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found the answer to my problem by doing a simple manipulation:

```
recdir()
{
    format=$format$spaces$vert

    for file in "$@"; do

            thisfile=$thisfile/$file

            if [ -d "$thisfile" ]; then
                    echo -e $format$dashes$file
                    recdir $(command ls $thisfile)
            fi

            thisfile=${thisfile%/*}
    done

    #tab=${tab%"$singletab"}
    format=${format%"$spaces$vert"}
}

recls()
{

    vert="|"
    dashes="-------"
    spaces="\t"
    echo "."
    echo "|"
    format=$vert
    for tryfile in "$@"; do
            echo -e $format$dashes$tryfile
            if [ -d "$tryfile" ]; then
                    thisfile=$tryfile
                    recdir $(command ls $tryfile)
            fi
    done

    unset vert dashes spaces format
}
```

This will print the desired result which I need. If you have a better and concise solution please comment.